# Problem computer not detecting graphics card

Tags: windows, 15.10

After I configured dual boot and booted up windows (with ubuntu 15.10) again none of my files are damaged or harmed and I thought I successfully configured a dual boot but now I have one problem. When I went to play some fallout new vegas and it then prompts me with "configuring settings to fit your hardware" and I thought that was odd then it says I have no graphics card and there is no selection for a graphics card. I also went to msi after burner and it didn't detect it there. But if I go to system information it says a gtx 960 is in use which is my graphics card. Thanks for reading any help would be greatly appreciated!

OS: windows 10 + ubuntu 15.10
the problem: games/programs can't detect graphics card

Comment: Well I thank you very much! I uninstalled linux and now for whatever reason my programs and games can detect my graphics card thanks a lot! I still have one issue though. So in the windows boot loader it gives me two options still ubuntu and windows. The only way I know of deleting the option "ubuntu" is for you to type in command prompt bcdedit /delete (special generated code) The only problem is I don't have the original code I created the option with is there another way?

Comment: Your graphics card is not detected in Windows? Then this is a Windows issue not an Ubuntu issue, please explain how this is Ubuntu related,

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCards This may help with your problem, a list of supported cards and their drivers is given.

Answer (score -2):

Steps to do:
1- Uninstall Ubuntu
2- Reinstall Ubuntu on a separate drive instead of installing side by side

Hopefully, it's gonna help you!

Comment: I thought if you partition a drive it would solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, fine so. Because if you gonna partition you drive for Ubuntu by allocating a fix space on drive, Ubuntu will work fine without any hardware driver issues.

Comment: How do you support this claim? How is the installation location related to whether or not the graphics card is detected properly?

Comment: -1 This is nonsense, it is as @the_Seppi says, what has this got to do with GPU detection? Please try to expand your answer to include your reasoning as to why this will work.

Comment: Reading your profile, a lack of information is a common issue in your posts, don't take this the wrong way, I only want to improve your content for the site but you MUST explain your self clearly when you post, this is why you receive downvotes, please browse so highly voted posts to see how to write a good answer http://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=votes